# two level splatter TCL

Tags: arguments, tcl, proc, splat, double-splat

If I have a procedure or a command in TCL, with variable number of arguments, one can use, if a list's elements are as an input, the "splatter" operator, for example:

```
set a [list "ko" ]
set m [ list "ok" "bang" ]
lappend a {*}$m
```

But, what if I want to "twice splatter"? I.e., flatten 2 levels? Using it twice, in  sequence, does not work:

```
set a [list "ko" ]
set m [ list [ list "ok" ] [ list "bang" ] ]
lappend a {*}{*}$m
```

Will error out on extra character.

Comment: I've seen people refer to `{*}` as the goatse operator. ***DO NOT GOOGLE THAT!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've noticed that `{*}` (deliberately) doesn't go two steps deep.

Your particular example isn't very indicative of the problem, so I suggest this:

```
set a [list "ko" ]
set m [list [list "a b" "c d"] [list "e f" "g h"]]
lappend a {*}$m
```

Here, we get `a` set to `ko {{a b} {c d}} {{e f} {g h}}`. Which isn't what you wanted. But we can instead do this:

```
lappend a {*}[concat {*}$m]
```

Which gives this: `ko {a b} {c d} {e f} {g h}`. That looks right.

---

But are we *really* doing the right thing here? Let's poke inside with our super-secret introspector, the `representation` command:

```
% tcl::unsupported::representation $m
value is a list with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x10085ec50, internal representation 0x103016790:0x0, string representation "{{a b} {c d}}..."
% tcl::unsupported::representation [concat {*}$m]
value is a string with a refcount of 1, object pointer at 0x10085de10, internal representation 0x1030052d0:0x10085f190, string representation "{a b} {c d} {..."
```

Uh oh! We've lost the list-ness. It's not a catastrophe, but it isn't what we wanted. We instead should really do:

```
foreach sublist $m {
    lappend a {*}$sublist
}
```

Well, that's more code but preserves list-ness (which would be good if you happened to have precious types on the leaves; core Tcl doesn't have such precious types, but some extensions do).

We can compare the timings:

```
% time {
    set a [list "ko" ]
    set m [list [list "a b" "c d"] [list "e f" "g h"]]
    lappend a {*}[concat {*}$m]
} 10000
2.852789 microseconds per iteration
% time {
    set a [list "ko" ]
    set m [list [list "a b" "c d"] [list "e f" "g h"]]
    foreach sublist $m {
        lappend a {*}$sublist
    }
} 10000
4.022959 microseconds per iteration
```

Oh…

```
% time {apply {{} {
    set a [list "ko" ]
    set m [list [list "a b" "c d"] [list "e f" "g h"]]
    lappend a {*}[concat {*}$m]
}}} 10000
2.4486125 microseconds per iteration
% time {apply {{} {
    set a [list "ko" ]
    set m [list [list "a b" "c d"] [list "e f" "g h"]]
    foreach sublist $m {
        lappend a {*}$sublist
    }
}}} 10000
1.6870501 microseconds per iteration
```

Hah! The type-correct one is better in a procedure(-like context).

Answer (score 1):

The `{*}` syntax doesn’t really flatten a list *per se*. Flattening is an execution-level activity, while argument expansion is a parsing-level activity.

```
% set a a
% lappend a {*}{{a b} {c d}}
```

In this example, the items in the list `{{a b} {c d}}` are spliced into the command line as two separate arguments:

```
% lappend a {a b} {c d}
a {a b} {c d}
```

If you need to flatten one more level, you should do so with a command “between” the expansions:

```
% lappend a {*}[concat {*}{{a b} {c d}}]
a a b c d
```

Documentation:
[concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)