# Splitting a list into multiple sub-lists, changing a particlular sub-list, and then rejoining all the sub-lists to form into a single new list?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have to write a code for doing the following steps.

1. Loading a file and saving the contents of a file into a list. (the file contains one column and 1223 rows of numbers, say in Matlab code `1:1:1223`)
2. Automatically Splitting the list into multiple sub-lists. (say each sub-list with 100 numbers, i.e. `1223/100 = 12.23` (approximately `13` sub-lists))
3. Increase the step-size in a particular sublist (say sub-list no. `3` contents from `201:1:300` to `201:0.5:300`).
4. After changing a particular sub-list, joining all the list to form a single list.

I have done the first step and I am struggling to do the steps 2, 3 and 4. I am unable to find a way to implement in tcl (I am a newbie for TCL). I have created a prototype in MATLAB (esp. to explain my need in the StackOverflow community). Following is the code I've written in MATLAB. But Ultimately, I have to implement this in TCL. (Using the `cell` concept in MATLAB, the whole process got easier)

```
clc
clear all
close all

Data_Initial = 1:1:1223;
Elements_in_List = 100;

% Dividing the list into Multiple sub-lists

Total_SubLists = floor(length(Data_Initial)/Elements_in_List);

if ((Total_SubLists*Elements_in_List) < length(Data_Initial))
    Total_SubLists = Total_SubLists + 1;
end

for i = 1: Total_SubLists

    Sublist_Begin_RowID = (i - 1)* Elements_in_List + 1;
    Sublist_End_RowID = i * Elements_in_List;

    if (i < Total_SubLists)
        SubLists{i} = Data_Initial(:, Sublist_Begin_RowID:Sublist_End_RowID);
    else 
        SubLists{i} = Data_Initial(:, Sublist_Begin_RowID:end, :);
    end
end

% Changing List NO. 3

K = 3;

A = SubLists{K};
A = A(1):0.5:A(end);
SubLists{K} = A;

% Re-Joining all the list to from a New data

Data_New = [];
for i = 1:length(SubLists)
    Data_New = horzcat(Data_New, SubLists{i});
end
```

Could anybody please help me do the steps 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Loading a file and saving the contents of a file into a list.

Use the [`open`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm) and [`split`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm) commands.

> Automatically Splitting the list into multiple sub-lists.

See this previous answer: [Split a list of numbers into smaller list based on a range in TCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066995/split-a-list-of-numbers-into-smaller-list-based-on-a-range-in-tcl)

> Increase the step-size in a particular sublist

You want to look at Tcl's [`lset`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm) that allows to access and manipulated structures of sub-lists using Tcl's zero-based index expressions.

```
% set superList [list [list 201 1 300] [list 202 1 300] [list 203 1 300]]
{201 1 300} {202 1 300} {203 1 300}
% lset superList 2 1 0.5
{201 1 300} {202 1 300} {203 0.5 300}
```

> After changing a particular sub-list, joining all the list to form a
>   single list.

One way to achieve this is the combined use of [`concat`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm) and the (parse-time) expansion operator `{*}`:

```
% concat {*}$superList
201 1 300 202 1 300 203 0.5 300
```

But this also depends on the levels of nesting in your super list: See [two level splatter TCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680723/two-level-splatter-tcl)

Comment: It is more advisable though, if doable, to compute a specific position based on the requirements in your steps (2) and (3), then use `lset` once with the computed position on the original list.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the answer. It is very helpful, I am implementing the code based on your answer.